# Symfony2: How to implement locale switcher with actual URI?

Tags: php, localization, symfony

All!
How to implement locale switcher with actual URI and parameters ??

Current page and locale (DE):

```
<en><DE>
mysite.com/de/controller/action/show/slug
```

User clicks on EN link

```
<EN><de>
mysite.com/en/controller/action/show/slug
```

locale switches, but the previous URI restored two

Any ideas ??
Thks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For the routing part, you can look at theses plugins:

- http://symfony2bundles.org/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle
- http://symfony2bundles.org/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

If you want to change your locale (do it very early with a kernel listener for example) :

> $container->get('session')->setLocale('en');